# Future prefect and Future perfect continuous tense

Tags: tenses

Can anyone please clarify/ explain when to use these two grammar tenses? Especially the future perfect continuous. It is quite confusing. Thanks.

Comment: Some confusing examples would be nice. As you present it, the subject is waaaaaay too broad.

Comment: Hold on Hela! English does not have a future tense, and continuous is an aspect, not a tense.

Answer (score 1):

**Future perfect**: future action completed before/by some future moment: I **will have seen** you before your meeting, at 3 pm, tomorrow.

**Future perfect continuous**: future result of a continuous/progressive action before/by some future moment (**progressive action or its result will probably be continuing/progressing beyond that future moment)** : I **will have been teaching** you for a while before your exam next year.

There's also this "special" usage describing anticipation/calculated prediction of a result:

1. Your friend has been in New York for over a week. He **will have visited** Central Park by now.
2. Your friend's English is very good after only 3 years of studying. He **will have been working** very hard at it to know so many words.